# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'List<PigeonInitializeResponse?>' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, compiler-errors, initialization

I need to run my project, and I'm getting the following error:

JUST PUT THE `import:'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';` IT GIVES ME THIS ERROR

C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.2/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:198:43: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'List<PigeonInitializeResponse?>' doesn't allow null.

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'PigeonInitializeResponse' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.2/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart').
- package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1
  Future<List<PigeonInitializeResponse?>> initializeCore() async {

```
Future<List<PigeonInitializeResponse?>> initializeCore() async { 
    final BasicMessageChannel<Object?> channel = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
        'dev.flutter.pigeon.FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore', codec,
        binaryMessenger: _binaryMessenger);
    final Map<Object?, Object?>? replyMap =
        await channel.send(null) as Map<Object?, Object?>?;
    if (replyMap == null) {
      PlatformException(
        code: 'channel-error',
        message: 'Unable to establish connection on channel.',
      );
    } else if (replyMap['error'] != null) {
      final Map<Object?, Object?> error =
          (replyMap['error'] as Map<Object?, Object?>?)!;
      throw PlatformException(
        code: (error['code'] as String?)!,
        message: error['message'] as String?,
        details: error['details'],
      );
    } else if (replyMap['result'] == null) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'null-error',
        message: 'Host platform returned null value for non-null return value.',
      );
    } else {
      return (replyMap['result'] as List<Object?>?)!
          .cast<PigeonInitializeResponse>();
    }
  }
```

After the error appears in debug, it contains a link that leads to the error, the code is not mine.

I'm having a lot of trouble solving this error, because I'm a beginner in flutter and the code is not mine, it's inside the packages.

I've done flutter clean and flutter pub get.

I made sure the dependencies are all up to date.

I configured firebase, google-services in build.gradle, classpath, apply plugin and implementation.

> flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo
    10.0.19044.2251], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (6 days ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Rafael Pereira\AppData\Local\Android\sdk       
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.    
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup 
      for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe        

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including  
      all of its default components

[!] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Rafael Pereira\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS 
      Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.53.20221101

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    •  
      Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    •
      Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19044.2251]
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript •
      Google Chrome 107.0.5304.121
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript •
      Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.56

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

## My code - file main.dart:

```
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' show FirebaseAuth, User;
import 'package:pigeon/pigeon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './login_page.dart';
import './next_page.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const LoginPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Mainpage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Mainpage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const NextPage();
            } else {
              return const LoginPage();
            }
          },
        ),
     );
}
```

## My code login_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';



class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(233, 30, 34, 88),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Login",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 18,
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 8,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Color.fromARGB(108, 217, 220, 221)),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "E-mail"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent[700],
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Logar',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: signIn,
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Esqueceu sua senha?'),
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future signIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    );
  }
}
```

I've appealed to some people, but nothing solved.

I tried simple things, but I'm a beginner and I end up being limited.

I made all the updates, and possible settings that could be interfering.

files pubspec.yaml:

## Firebase

firebase_auth: ^4.1.4
firebase_messaging: ^14.1.2
firebase_database: ^10.0.6
firebase_core: ^2.3.0
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.2

## Dart Pigeon

pigeon: ^4.2.6

## Flutterfire

flutterfire_cli: ^0.2.7

Comment: Please paste code as text, not pictures.

Comment: can you include the packages you installed from pubspec.yaml

Comment: Okay, now it's clearer

Comment: I think it's because your forgot `throw` in the first if statement.

Comment: in which file? @Hydra

Comment: `initializeCore` function `if (replyMap == null)`

Comment: It´s not worked @Hydra